# How can I query Object Properties in an OWL ontology

Tags: owl, protege, object-properties, owlready

I am working with the [FoodOn](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FoodOntology/foodon/master/foodon.owl) ontology and need to figure out if a certain class is somehow related to another class. Typical use case: Can a vegan person eat honey? No, because honey is a subsub class of "invertebrate animal food product"!

I am using the python owlready2 library which allows me to run SPARQL queries and query subclass relations like this:

```
SELECT  ?class
WHERE
{
  # honey
  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UBERON_0036016> rdfs:subClassOf* ?class .
  # animal food product
  ?class rdfs:subClassOf* <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/FOODON_00001176>
}
```

This code gives me the full subclass path between honey and animal food product - great.

My problem is, that the relationship is not always that of a subclass. Let's look at "vegetarian food product" using the Protege editor:

[image: Protege screenshot]

We can see that "vegetarian food product" is a subclass of "food product by organism" but at the same time it is also **equivalent to 'food product'
and (not ('derives from' some
('invertebrate animal' or 'vertebrate animal')))**.

If I look at all triples using SPARQL I get the subclass relationship but the equivalentClass is just a bnode:

```
(rdflib.term.URIRef('http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf'),
  rdflib.term.URIRef('http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/FOODON_00002381')),
(rdflib.term.URIRef('http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#equivalentClass'),
  rdflib.term.BNode('5846'))

[stripped some output]
```

1. Why does SPARQL not return all relationships?
2. How can I query for all classes that are either a subclass of 'vegetarian food product' or related to it by **some other object property**?
3. Also, how can I query for the **'AND'** and **'OR'** component in the example above?

I do accept non-python solutions as long as it can be automated. Protege has a DL Query tab but I think that I cannot export the results using the UI...

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds interesting. Can you link a self contained code file/notebook? For easy reproducibility of the problem?